# Fill options with function using mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm trying to fill in the different options on a form calling objects from a database using a different php file. Here is my code:

PHP Code (`functions.php`):

```
<?php /* Gets values from sql and inserts into html options values */ 

function selectOptions($column, $table){      
// fetch records
$sql = "SELECT" . $column. "FROM" . $table. "ORDER BY Id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
//check there are more than 0 rows
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                       
      echo '<option>' .$row['$column']. '</option>';  
  }
}
else {
  echo '<option>No results!</option>'; }  } ?>
```

#### HTML code:

```
<?php 
  require "php/dbconnect.php";
  require "php/functions.php";
?> 
<select class="form-control">
  <option>SUBJECT</option>
   <?php
    selectOptions("Subjects", "general_subjects");
   ?>
</select>
```

I use this function multiple times for different forms, so I figured having it in its own file would be the best approach but it does not work. When I use the function without variables inside the index.php file, it seems to work. I don't know what I am doing wrong

EDIT: Image of what it should be doing [Image of index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRbZ4.png)

Comment: So you want every time you choose a selection, the php function will execute?

Comment: I want the options to be available as soon as the page loads because students will select 3 things: grade, Subject, Branch. The function works if I use it in the index.php file on the other two Forms but I would like to populate the options using the functions.php file because it's kinda redundant to keep copy/pasting the same code. . Thank you for your help

Comment: Output the SQL query you create. You’ll see what is going wrong. Hint: spaces. Always check for errors on the queries you run!

Comment: Forgive me if I'm way off, but I have similar code in a project I'm working on. I run my query, and in a while loop (i.e. while($data = $sql->fetch()) )I put every row inside an element. In your case, it's an option tag. I would try to code it out, but I'm sure someone with better skills will get to it before me. It would look something like <option><?php echo $row['columnName'];?></option> Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question correctly. You're already doing that.

Comment: Hi its me again would you try  $sql = "SELECT " . $column. " FROM " . $table. " ORDER BY Id";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add spaces to your sql query. Also you need to access the `$column` variable properly. You shouldn't wrap it around single quotes as it is a variable. You also have a variable scope issue as `$conn` does not exist

```
function selectOptions($conn, $column, $table) {
// fetch records
    $sql = "SELECT `" . $column . "` FROM `" . $table . "` ORDER BY Id"; #add spaces
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
//check there are more than 0 rows
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<option>' . $row[$column] . '</option>'; #remove single quotes
        }
    } else {
        echo '<option>No results!</option>';
    }
}
```

When you call the above function, add the `echo` keyword

```
<?php
  echo selectOptions($conn, "Subjects", "general_subjects"); #echo the function
   ?>
```

Comment: Nope, nothing. I noticed you had extra single quotes before the double quotes in the $sql variable. Are those needed?

Comment: those are needed just incase the table and column names are sql reserved words. They are called backticks.

Comment: Ok, but that $conn variable is coming from the "dbconnect.php"; that is called on the index.php file. Should I include it on the functions.php file instead? Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it

Comment: my pleasure ;).

Answer (score 0):

Would you try editing your `function.php` `sql` part like this

```
  $sql = "SELECT " . $column. " FROM " . $table. " ORDER BY Id";
```

i think the spaces is the reason that it's not returning data

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't notice that. Appreciate the input :0)